# How to disable thumbnail filter for a specific template part or image size?

Tags: theme-development, filters, post-thumbnails, images

I am filtering post_thumbnail_html in my theme to modify the output of my image tags. I have one template part that I would like this filter not to apply to. It uses an image-size that is used no were else in the theme. So I am looking for a way to have this filter not apply on a specific template part or for a specific image size, either way works. Is this possible.

I don't think the filter itself matters, but just in case here it is:

```
 if (! function_exists('_sf_responsive_img') ) :
 function _sf_responsive_img($html, $post_id, $post_thumbnail_id, $size, $attr) {
     //make image links
     $attachment_id = $post_thumbnail_id;
     $default = wp_get_attachment_image_src($attachment_id);
     $size = 'fd-sm';
     $small = wp_get_attachment_image_src($attachment_id, $size);
     $size = 'fd-med';
     $med = wp_get_attachment_image_src($attachment_id, $size);
     $size = 'fd-lrg';
     $lrg = wp_get_attachment_image_src($attachment_id, $size);
     //create image tag with queries
     $html = '<img src="'.$default[0].'"';
     $html .= 'data-interchange="['.$default[0].', (default)],';
     $html .= '['.$small[0].', (only screen and (min-width: 320px))],';
     $html .= '['.$med[0].', (only screen and (min-width: 768px))],';
     $html .= '['.$lrg[0].', (only screen and (min-width: 1024px))],';
     $html .='">';
     return $html;
 }
 add_filter('post_thumbnail_html', '_sf_responsive_img', 5, 5);
 endif; // ! _sf_responsive_img exists
```

Answer (score 2):

Probably the simplest solution is to remove the filter before output:

```
// remove the filter
remove_filter('post_thumbnail_html', '_sf_responsive_img', 5, 5);
// output template
get_template_part( 'something' );
// add the filter back on if other code below outputs thumbs that need the filter
add_filter('post_thumbnail_html', '_sf_responsive_img', 5, 5);
```